# Checking role in has-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Cancan so I need to check a users roles. Have a has_many relationship with Users -> userroles(reference id's) -> roles(name of each role, with the role being in the name column).

In my user model I have a function: role?(role), ie `role?(:admin)`, that checks to see if the user has a role.

```
def role?(role)
   roles.include? role.to_s
end
```

This doesn't work, do I have to specify the name column?

Solved: I'll put the answer down after the time elapses.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a string to an object

```
def role?(role)
  !roles.first(:conditions => {:name => role.to_s}).nil?
end
```

Try this?

Alternative based on Dmitriy Likhten's answer

```
def role?(role)
  roles.collect{|r| r.name }.include? role.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always just filter it in-line...

```
roles.select(&:to_s).include?(role.to_s)
```

The difference between mine and Jimmy's approach is dependent on whether or not the role is already in memory. If it is, filtering is faster, if not a query is better.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `collect` instead of `select`? `select` will just return the objects, `collect` will return an array of strings. You're also assuming the `.to_s` method on a role object returns its name, which it probably doesn't